# Strange remoting connection problem

Tags: .net, remoting

In trying to configure a .NET remoting setup over TCP, I've been having problems accepting outside connections (connections from any computer not on my LAN). I did some investigation and hit netstat -a as soon as my friend started to connect. Here's what I saw:

> TCP    0.0.0.0:2594           Taylor-PC:0            LISTENING
>     ...
>     TCP    192.168.1.102:2594     24-155-7-16:63588      ESTABLISHED
>     TCP    192.168.1.102:62488    192.168.0.100:1554     SYN_SENT

Now here's the weird part: 24.155.7.16 is my friend's IP (modified) and it says the connection is established. But the connection hangs until it times out. I then found out that 192.168.0.100 is *his* local address on *his* network. Something screwy's going on somewhere. My server and client are both TCPChannels, the latter initialized 'new TCPChannel( 0 ).' Localhost connections work when I run a client on the same machine as the server, but I can't accept remote connections. There is no port forwarding or firewall  issue.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Does your friend's subnet have the same IP address range as your subnet (e.g. 192.168.0.*)? I've had similar problems before... more due to router configuration than anything else because of subnets with identical IP address ranges. Has he tried directly connected to the internet? Or is he or you able to change your subnet?

Comment: He's got 192.168.0.*, and I 192.168.1.*.

Answer (score 0):

Check again the firewalls in the server side, like Windows Firewall/Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) in Services